# Does accepting a handler instead of returning a result have a name?

Tags: terminology, interfaces

```
def create() -> socket.socket:
    ...
    return sock

def create_(func: callable)-> None:
    ...
    func(sock)
    return
```

What are the names of those two interfaces between* a socket creator and code using that socket?

Perhaps touch on situations in which one is considerably more appropriate.

<sub>* - sockets are just an example application</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With respect to functional programming, I think the term you may be looking for is [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). This is contrasted with returning a result directly like in your first example.

Comment: Cool, you named both: `continuation-passing style`; `returning a result directly`. That's an answer.

Comment: In object oriented programming this is called message passing to an output port.

Answer (score 3):

In your code example, `func` is commonly called a *callback function*.

As far as I'm aware, there's no real name for the method itself, other than describing it as using a callback function. Continuation methods fill the same functional requirement but their implementation is conceptually different.

Comment: +1 `return an object`  vs `accept a callback` is a valid answer. I am accepting the other one because it taught me the term continuation-passing.

Comment: This only names the structure used. Just because you have a callback function doesn't mean you have to pass it a result.

Comment: One difference in a callback function is that they _typically_ take two arguments, one of which is null: the result, and an error.  This make them more applicable in older procedural or OO style languages.

Comment: @user949300: It's significantly more common to have two callbacks (success and error), not a single callback where you have to nullcheck to see which parameter is not null.